# Converting char-date-char

Tags: sql, oracle

The column is defined as VARCHAR.
The data in this column:

> 2012-03-11 12:10:00.0 IST

I want to get only the date part.
What is the best way to do it?

I tired to convert it to date:

> to_char(to_date('2012-03-11 12:10:00.0 IST',
>   'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')

But got an error: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Why do you have date/time data in a varchar column? Why don't you have a datetime column instead?

Comment: It does end, your varchar2 column doesn't stop at `DD`, see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: @kenny - What `DATE` do you want?  Since an Oracle `DATE` has neither a time zone nor fractional seconds, do you want to ignore both when you convert the data to a `DATE`?  Or do you want to convert the time to a standard time zone (i.e. GMT/UTC)?  Are you sure you don't want to convert the string to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` that would support fractional seconds and a time zone?

Answer (score 5):

Update: If I get you right, you only want the date **part** but **not convert** it to date?
Then do this:

```
select SUBSTR('2012-03-11 12:10:00.0 IST', 1, 10)
```

If you also want to convert it to date then do this:

```
select to_date(SUBSTR('2012-03-11 12:10:00.0 IST', 1, 10))
```

Comment: -1, the OP has the right idea, convert to a date first. You're effectively doing date conversion with char tools.

Comment: +1 Given a constant datetime format in the original string, this is the simplest way to convert it **from a string**.

Comment: @MarkBannister, it's also the most likely to fail silently and the most likely to give you the wrong result. Yes if it's a _constant datetime format_ then it'll work but this is stored as a varchar and I don't believe the potential pitfalls are worth it for about 20 characters of code and a microsecond or two.

Comment: @Ben - Surely then the problem is not the solution proposed, but the original design? Don't use VARCHAR to represent a DATETIME.  Even if that's the source, add a pre-processing step to validate and parse the input, then you can have a DATETIME field, and have absolute confidence that you have what you *think* you have?

Comment: @Dems, it's true that one should store dates as DATEs or TIMESTAMPs. However, sometimes a VARCHAR is all one has to work with on a legacy application.

Comment: @Dems, yes, of course the source of the problem is the datatype, however, working with what there is to **ensure** it's done correctly you need to convert it to a date first.

Answer (score 1):

juergen d is good and may be fastest. However you can do it this way too:
`select cast(to_timestamp('2012-03-11 12:10:00.0 IST', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 "IST"') as date) from dual;`